# Multiple CMD commands C#

Tags: c#, process

Currently I am programming a program which controls the CMD.
The problem is that with my code I can run a single command and then the CMD closes.
But I need to fill in follow-up commands (like filling in passwords).

My current code is:

```
cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmdProcess.Start();
cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(txt_Command.Text);
cmdProcess.StandardInput.Flush();
cmdProcess.StandardInput.Close();
txt_Output.Text = cmdProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

I understand that my code explicitly says that it should close. But when I remove that line the command won't be executed. Anyone who knows why?

What I want is for the CMD to stay open. I hope someone can help.

With kind regards

Comment: You can invoke multiple commands using `&` operator

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply, this is not what i am looking for. I first need to send a single command, and then I need to follow up with other different commands. These commands differ to the situation so I can't use the & statement.

Comment: Have you tried using the ```-k``` switch on ```cmd.exe```? That way the CMD remains open.

Comment: @Shawn I have tried it but my code says the cmd should close. This still closes the window. But when I remove the line from my code, the program gets stuck because it is waiting to be closed before it can execute.

Comment: This is also an option but I have issues with this solution too. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61323944/ssh-connection-c-sharp-not-displaying-all-information)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we need to understand why you need to run the commands in the same context. If you need the return values/output, why can't  you just run your command and redirect the output to a file with mycommand.exe >> %temp%\output.txt?

Comment: Thank you for you reply. What I need to do is make an SSH connection with a linux divice. I know that there are ways to do this with libraries but I need to do it with cmd. When I enter the command "ssh username@IP-adress" cmd then asks me for the password. But the cmd closes before I can enter a password. So I need to keep cmd open so I can the enter the password. This works when i manually control cmd, but when I run it through my program the command can't be executet before cmd is closed. (as explained in the question).